# How to separate J2EE web application for apache and tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat

I want to setup and Apache and Tomcat together and deploy my war file on the this setup. My question is how I separate my application for apache and tomcat ?Please give me example.

Thanks
Kumara

Answer (score 0):

Generally I place static files as well as rewriting, AJP, and other customization filters at the Apache layer, pass through necessary URLs over to Tomcat and Servlet processing.

If you are completely contained in the .war and don't have a need for the features of a web server, Tomcat is perfectly happy serving HTTP directly.